# Java implement Iterable, for each and method

Tags: java, collections, foreach, iterator, iterable

I've this exercise with an algorithm to implement. I have this main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person a = new Person("Tony");
        Person c = new Person("Luke");
        Person o = new Person("Ann");

        a.addFriends(c);
        a.addFriends(o);

        for(Person p: a.contacts())
            System.out.println(p);
}
```

If I replace "a.contacts()" with "a" and use this class, the code works! But How can I implement the for-each loop with "a.contacts()"?? Thanks

```
class Person implements Iterable<Person> {

    private Set<Person> friends = new HashSet<Person>();   
    private String name;

    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addFriends(Person o){                
        friends.add(o);
   }

    public String toString(){
        return this.name;
    }


    @Override
    public Iterator<Person> iterator() {
        Iterator<Person> i = friends.iterator();
        return i;
    }

    //Here the contacts method to implement!!

}
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want. Even a simple getter will do as the question is described now. `public Set<Person> contacts() { return friends; }`. It will merely return the friends set, and will use its (The `Set`'s) iterator. No idea if that's what you want though.

Comment: P.S. If `name` is never changed (a value is assigned only in the constructor), it is usually a good practice to declare it as `final`. (It is not related to your question in any way, just a tip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to run a loop for `Person` so the place next to `:` should be a collection of type `Person`.

```
    for(Person p: a.contacts())
        System.out.println(p);
```

You could either choose a `List` or `Set` for this and return the collection from `contacts()` method of class `Person`.

In this case since you've have `Set` so return it.

```
public Set<Person> contacts() {
    return friends;
}
```

Comment: Why not hide the implementation details and return a `Collection<Person>` instead?

Comment: Makes sense... but since the OP is confused about what to return... I thought to keep it simple!!

Answer (score 1):

Let your `contacts()` method have a return type of `Set of Person`....

```
public Set<Person> contacts() {
    return friends;
}
```

So now the below will work...

```
for (Person p : a.contacts()) {
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with a Collection<T> is not the same as using Iterable<T>. The implementation of Iterable<T> allows for lazy loading while the Collection<T> based implementation requires you to fill the whole collection prior to returning it. The correct way to deal with your requirement is by implementing the following method inside the class `Person´:

```
public Iterable<Person> contacts() {
  return new Iterable<Person>() {
    public Iterator<Person> iterator() {
      return friends.iterator();
    }
  };
}
```